# Compare two tables and insert all records with added or removed status in 3rd table using SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, stored-procedures

I have table A and table B . I have to compare this tables records and insert data to table C using SQL Server procedure in below format

table A

```
  name
  A
  B
  C
  D
  E
  F
  G
```

table B

```
  name
  A
  B
  Q
  C
  D
  F
  G
```

table c should be like below. it has an extra field 'status' to mention record is added or removed.

```
name   status
A  
B
Q      newly added
C
D      
E      removed
F
G
```

I know we can compare 2 tables and find added or removed records using EXCEPT and UNION operations. But in this case, I have to integrate that records with unchanged records and should place that added or removed records in correct position.

Comment: first of all show us your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which order do you want to accomplish at the end you can use this:

```
select name, max(status), descr from(
select 
    coalesce(a.col, b.col) name,
    coalesce(a.descr, b.descr) descr,
    case
        when a.col is null then 'newly added'
        when b.col is null then 'removed'
    end status
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
from a a
left join b b on b.col = a.col
union
select 
    coalesce(a.col, b.col) name,
    coalesce(a.descr, b.descr) descr,
    case
        when a.col is null then 'newly added'
        when b.col is null then 'removed'
    end status
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
from b b
left join a a on b.col = a.col) A
group by name, descr
order by max(rn);
```

And then if you want to order by how it is in table a then in first select select `from b left join a` and in your second select `from a left join b` and if you want to oder by how it is in table b then in first select select `from a left join b` and in your second select `from b left join a`.

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=196ae8674f3b82c4e6aa7a560ba3fd7d) with the last requested samle data.

Comment: Hi @VBoka .. i checked latest demo.. what i am expecting is, the removed record 'F' should be between 'E' and 'G ' as in input file.. that is all the records should be in its correct position.. but in code output, 'F' is in between 'C' and 'D'.. Can you help me on these ?

Comment: @sahira please note that you can see only first 10 rows in this example provided...

Comment: i could see 13 rows VBoka.. but i am stuck with record ordering issue.. that is position of 'F'.

Comment: @VBoka..are you able to help me on that ordering issue ? 'F' position..

Comment: Hi @sahira no, I suggest to open a new question... and accept one answer from here are correct because now you have a lot of new conditions and new example...

Comment: Ok VBoka.. i will accept this answer and will post new question

Comment: Hi @sahira, a vote up for the user GMB, because a answer was helpful, would be nice...

Comment: @VBoka..Posted this as new question.. please help me if you can..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60076543/compare-2-tables-and-insert-all-records-with-added-or-removed-status-in-another

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a `full join` and conditional logic:

```
select 
    coalesce(a.name, b.name) name,
    case
        when a.name is null then 'newly added'
        when b.name is null then 'removed'
    end status
from tablea a
full join tableb b on b.name = a.name
order by name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d75d52f5aa7d7632ecce5a7784533b6a)**:

```
name | status     
:--- | :----------
A    | null       
B    | null       
C    | null       
D    | null       
E    | removed    
F    | null       
G    | null       
Q    | newly added
```

Comment: thank you.. but the newly added record 'Q' should not be in last position.. it should be under 'B' as in the input file...

Comment: @sahira: to keep records *in order*, you need a column in your dataset that can be used for that purpose. It is not showing in your sample data, so I just ordered by `name`. Do you have such a column?

Comment: yes GMB.. original tables A and B has auto increment id column also.. original name columns will not be in alphabetical order. so we cant sort by using that

Comment: @sahira: ok, so you can just use that to order the records.

Comment: ..But even i order it using id column, i will not get in exact order as input tables

Comment: @sahira: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60072091/edit) your question to add the id column to both tables and to the resultset so we can understand what you expect.

Comment: Hi @sahira This is a great answer here so I do not want to open a new one with this. Does this answer your question: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9b855c200176169925a9c7aa881c11e1  I used this answer of course... GMB vote up, all credits to you... Just trying to help cheers!

Comment: @ VBoka..great answer..thank you so much..i have one doubt .. in my actual input tables i have several columns like description.. this code will work in that case also ? Can you please update the code by adding one more field like 'description' in table A, table B and table C.. it will be very much helpful for me..

Comment: Hi @sahira, what is in description ? Type varchar with some text ?

Comment: Hi @sahira , here it is: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fc03dea372c6a2a9a8ed5430db6061df

Comment: thanks  @VBoka.. bu there is one issue ..if i give name field like A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J for table a, and A,B,M,N,O,C,D,E,G,H,I,J for table b . the expected ouput is like in order A,B,M,N,O,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J. But code output is like A,B,M,N,O,C,F,D,E,G,H,I,J..can you please check that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a some union  and left join

```
select  A.name, case when is null t1.name then 'newly addedd' end 
from A 
left  JOIN  (
  select  A.name from A 
  union B.name from B
) t1 

union 
select  B.name, case when is null t1.name then 'delete' end 
from B
left  JOIN  (
  select  A.name from A 
  union B.name from B
) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with below query ([SQL FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d67d5ca8cdb4790024a3598cd8377b87)):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_records
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO C(name, status)
    SELECT AB.name, AB.status FROM(
    SELECT (case when A.name is null then B.name else A.name end) as name,
       (CASE 
        WHEN A.name is null THEN 'newly added'
        WHEN B.name is null THEN 'removed'
     END) AS status
    FROM A
    FULL JOIN B on B.name = A.name
  ) as AB
  ORDER by AB.name

END
```

Comment: thank you.. but we can not order using name column . because in original table,  name should not be in alphabetical order

Comment: Then add you as per required column

Answer (score 0):

You should use FULL OUTER JOIN.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE(
    [name] char(1)
)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE(
    [name] char(1)
)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G')
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES ('A'),('B'),('Q'),('C'),('D'),('F'),('G')
SELECT 
    IIF(T1.name IS NULL,T2.name,T1.name) as 'Name',
    CASE WHEN T1.name IS NULL THEN 'newly added' WHEN T2.name IS NULL THEN 'removed' ELSE '' END as 'Status'
FROM @table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN @table2 T2 ON T1.name = T2.name
```

There ise one more possible method:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE(
    [name] char(1)
)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE(
    [name] char(1)
)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G')
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES ('A'),('B'),('Q'),('C'),('D'),('F'),('G')
SELECT 
    T1.name as 'Full_List',
    IIF(T2.name IS NOT NULL,'','removed') as 'Status'
FROM @table1 T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table2 T2 ON T1.name = T2.name
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    T2.name,
    IIF(T1.name IS NULL,'Added','') 

FROM @table2 T2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @table1 T1 ON T1.name = T2.name
WHERE T1.name IS NULL
```