# Compare two tables and insert all records with added or removed status in another table using SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have table A and table B . I have to compare this tables records and insert data to table C using SQL Server procedure in below format.

table A

```
  name   description
   A      desc A
   B      desc B
   C      desc C
   D      desc D
   E      desc E
   F      desc F
   G      desc G
   H      desc H
   I      desc I
   J      desc J
```

table B

```
 name  description
 A        desc A
 B        desc B
 M        desc M
 N        desc N
 O        desc O
 C        desc C
 D        desc D
 E        desc E
 G        desc G
 H        desc H
 I        desc I
 J        desc J
```

Table c should be like below. It has an extra field 'status' to mention record is added or removed.

```
 name  description  status
 A        desc A
 B        desc B   
 M        desc M    newly added
 N        desc N    newly added
 O        desc O    newly added
 C        desc C
 D        desc D
 E        desc E
 F        desc F    removed
 G        desc G
 H        desc H
 I        desc I
 J        desc J
```

I tried code like below

```
select 
   coalesce(a.name, b.name) name,
   coalesce(a.description, b.description) description,
  case
    when a.name is null then 'newly added'
    when b.name is null then 'removed'
  end status
from tablea a
full join tableb b on b.name = a.name
```

But in output, newly added records  M,N,O is coming in last position.. M,N,O should be under B as in input table. I am not getting output in order as mentioned in table C.

Comment: Is it okay if the row with `removed`(`F`) goes to first position and others as you expect?

Comment: No arun.. F should be in correct position..ie under 'E'.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question: [compare 2 tables and insert all records with added or removed status in 3rd table using sql server procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072091/compare-2-tables-and-insert-all-records-with-added-or-removed-status-in-3rd-tabl)

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need an `order by`?

```
select coalesce(a.name, b.name) as name,
       coalesce(a.description, b.description) as description,
       (case when a.name is null then 'newly added'
             when b.name is null then 'removed'
        end) as status
from tablea a full join
     tableb b
     on b.name = a.name
order by coalesce(a.name, b.name)
```

Comment: No.. can not order by name. the order should be exact as in input tables

Comment: @sahira Nope - no such thing as "order in a table". Tables are, by definition, unordered. If you want an order, any query that needs it must include an order by clause. If you have no column that defines the order you need, you are out of luck.

Comment: question updated with slight changes (added extra id column ) and posted as new question..please help if you can..here is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087802/compare-two-tables-and-combine-records-with-status-in-sql-server-procedure

Answer (score 1):

If the data is valid, why you are worried about how it is ordered when being inserted?

The relation in the relation theory is represented in the SQL with a table. And the relation is not ordered. So, you are not allowed to defined how rows are ordered when they are materialized - and you should not care about this.

Even you have a unique criteria on which you can order the results, there is no guarantee that the engine will insert the rows in that way. In all cases (except when you have identity column), the `ORDER BY` is ignored during the `INSERT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    VALUES (1), (2), (3)
) DS ([col])
ORDER BY [col];


SELECT *
INTO #DS
FROM 
(
    VALUES (1), (2), (3)
) DS ([col])
ORDER BY [col];
```

[image]

So, ask yourself the following questions:

- Do I have a unique criteria by which to order the values?
- Can I perform this ordering when data is extracted?

Comment: the ordering criteria is " the order of records in input tables"..

Comment: question updated with slight changes (added extra id column ) and posted as new question..please help if you can..here is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087802/compare-two-tables-and-combine-records-with-status-in-sql-server-procedure

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try it with a merge
First insert the Data from Table A into Table C and then

```
 Merge into TableC AS TRG
  USING (Select Name
  ,Description 
  FROM TableB) AS SRC
  ON TRG.Name=SRC.Name
  WHEN NOT MATCHED  BY TARGET 
  THEN INSERT (Name
  ,Description 
  ,[Status]
  )
  VALUES (Name
  ,Description 
  ,'newly added')
  WHEN NOT MATCHED  BY SOURCE
  THEN UPDATE SET TRG.[Status]='removed';
```

Sorry about the formating, it is my first post here :)

Comment: above code has some syntax error.. can you fix that ?

Comment: 'Using' before the select was missing, should be fine now

Comment: still has error 'SQL Error [207] [S0001]: Invalid column name 'Status'.'

Comment: in your description of table C it has a column called status. and in this column, we are inserting the 'removed' or 'newly added' content

Answer (score 1):

***Data in the table is not ordered***.

You have to have some `identity column` to keep the order you want. Since you do not have any identity column in your table, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to create virtual identity column.

Below will work for your case. but it's an ugly way. Not sure about the performance.

```
WITH tablebrow 
     AS (SELECT *, Row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn 
         FROM   #tableb), 
     tablearow 
     AS (SELECT *, Row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn 
         FROM   #tablea) 

SELECT COALESCE(a.NAME, b.NAME)               NAME, 
       COALESCE(a.description, b.description) description, 
       CASE 
         WHEN a.NAME IS NULL THEN 'newly added' 
         WHEN b.NAME IS NULL THEN 'removed' 
       END status 
FROM   tablearow a 
       FULL JOIN tablebrow b 
              ON b.NAME = a.NAME 
ORDER  BY Isnull(b.rn, (SELECT tr.rn 
                        FROM   tablebrow tr 
                        WHERE  description = (SELECT TOP 1 description 
                                              FROM   tablearow t 
                                              WHERE  t.rn < a.rn 
                                              ORDER  BY t.rn DESC)))
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b1f5053d69df261a404b26b140105463)

*Note for DEMO example:  I have removed `I` row as well along with `F` for testing*

Comment: in actual input tables A and B, i have an identity column 'id' as autoincrement... so can you just update your code without using virtual identity column.. i mean please use original id column..

Comment: @arun..question updated with slight changes (added extra id column ) and posted as new question..please help if you can..here is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087802/compare-two-tables-and-combine-records-with-status-in-sql-server-procedure

Comment: can you please check my updated question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087802/compare-two-tables-and-combine-records-with-status-in-sql-server-procedure?noredirect=1#comment106273102_60087802