# Compare two tables and combine records with status in SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table A and table B . I have to compare this 2 tables records and return data using SQL Server procedure in below format.

table A

```
id   name   description
 1    A      desc A
 2    B      desc B
 3    C      desc C
 4    D      desc D
 5    E      desc E
 6    F      desc F
 7    G      desc G
 8    H      desc H
 9    I      desc I
 10   J      desc J
```

table B

```
id   name  description
 1    A        desc A
 2    B        desc B
 3    M        desc M
 4    N        desc N
 5    O        desc O
 6    C        desc C
 7    D        desc D
 8    E        desc E
 9    G        desc G
 10   H        desc H
 11   I        desc I
 12   J        desc J
```

Expected output is like below. It has an extra field 'status' to mention record is added or removed.

```
name  description  status
A        desc A
B        desc B   
M        desc M    newly added
N        desc N    newly added
O        desc O    newly added
C        desc C
D        desc D
E        desc E
F        desc F    removed
G        desc G
H        desc H
I        desc I
J        desc J
```

I tried code like below

```
  select 
     coalesce(a.name, b.name) name,
     coalesce(a.description, b.description) description,
   case
      when a.name is null then 'newly added'
      when b.name is null then 'removed'
   end status
     from tablea a
     full join tableb b on b.name = a.name
```

But in output, newly added records M,N,O is coming in last position.. M,N,O should be under B as in input table. I am not getting output in order as mentioned in expected output.

Comment: use order by Id

Comment: @ Atk .. even i order by using id, i wont get it in exact order in the expected output

Comment: can you provide your create table and insert scripts so that i can test at my end?

Comment: @Atk create table a (id int, name varchar(10), description varchar(20));insert into a values (1,'A', 'descr A');insert into a values (2,'B', 'descr B');insert into a values (3,'C', 'descr C');insert into a values (4,'D', 'descr D');insert into a values (5,'E', 'descr E');insert into a values (6,'F', 'descr F');insert into a values (7,'G', 'descr G');insert into a values (8,'H', 'descr H');insert into a values (9,'I', 'descr I');insert into a values (10,'J', 'descr J');

Comment: @ Atk  create table b ( id int, name varchar(10), description varchar(20));insert into b values (1,'A', 'descr A');insert into b values (2,'B', 'descr B');insert into b values (3,'M', 'descr M');insert into b values (4,'N', 'descr N');insert into b values (5,'O', 'descr O');insert into b values (6,'C', 'descr C');insert into b values (7,'D', 'descr D');insert into b values (8,'E', 'descr E');insert into b values (9,'G', 'descr G');insert into b values (10,'H', 'descr H');insert into b values (11,'I', 'descr i');insert into b values (12,'J', 'descr i');

Comment: using order by name and discription  field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in other question, I have updated my answer to add your identity column instead of `row_number()`

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.NAME, b.NAME) NAME, 
       COALESCE(a.description, b.description) description, 
       CASE 
         WHEN a.NAME IS NULL THEN 'newly added' 
         WHEN b.NAME IS NULL THEN 'removed' 
       END status 
FROM   a FULL JOIN b ON b.NAME = a.NAME 
ORDER  BY ISNULL(b.id, (SELECT sb.id 
                        FROM   b sb 
                        WHERE  description = (SELECT TOP 1 description 
                                              FROM   a sa 
                                              WHERE sa.id < a.id 
                                              ORDER  BY sa.id DESC)))
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1e5036adcaee241ed68dcecb66e2b166)

Note: You can use `name` instead of `description` in the subquery based on your need.

Comment: @arun..this query gives following error while executing in my DB.. Can you please help ?
Error : Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: @sahira, Do you have duplicates in your tables?

Comment: Otherwise it wont throw this error. Somehow SubQuery is returning more than one value.  Do one thing, change the `description` to `name` in the last subquery and check.`.....isnull(b.id,(select  tr.id from b tr where name = (select TOP 1 name .....` @sahira

Comment: can you just update your demo code by using name instead of description ?

Comment: Ok. [Check here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7efbfab6125fcb33b3a408903bc24b9) @sahira

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

`with t as (select 
     coalesce(a.name, b.name) name,
     coalesce(a.description, b.description) description,
   case
      when a.name is null then 'newly added'
      when b.name is null then 'removed'
   end status,
   case
       when a.id is null then b.id else a.id 
       end id
     from table1 a
     full join table2 b on b.name = a.name)
     select name,description,status from t order by id`